# add "data-id" to <td> datatables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

**It's possible to do this :**

The data that I want to enter I get a method implemented from a servlet using json, which goes perfectly.

The problem is that I want to add to the last  a variable "data-id"

```
$('#tbl_bienSeleccionado').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "columnDefs": [
                {"className": "text-center", "targets": "_all"}
            ],
            "aaData": res.lista,                
            "columns": [
                {"data": "idbien"},
                {"data": "nombre"},
                {"data": "description"},
                {"data": "persona"},
                {"data": "ubicacion"},
                {"data": "estado"},
                {"data": "departamento"},
                {"data": "idbien", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {                          
                    $(nTd).html("<a href='javascript:;'  class='btn btn-danger  btn-circle remove' title='Agregar'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a>");    
                }
            ]
});
```

I need add: js data-id='res.lista.idbien' into td → result  html:

```
<td data-id='123" >
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle edit" title="Editar">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried $(nTd).data('id', '123' )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $('#tbl_bienSeleccionado').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "columnDefs": [
                {"className": "text-center", "targets": "_all"}
            ],
            "aaData": res.lista,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "idbien"},
                {"data": "nombre"},
                {"data": "descripcion"},
                {"data": "persona"},
                {"data": "ubicacion"},
                {"data": "estado"},
                {"data": "departamento"},
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a href='javascript:;'  class='btn btn-danger btn-circle remove' title='Quitar'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td>");
                    }}
            ],
            createdRow: function (row, data, indice) {

                $(row).find("td:eq(7)").attr('data-id', data.idbien);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. There is a row call back function. You can insert a html to the  8th column like this.

```
var edithtml = '<td data-id={id} >' +
                  '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle   edit" title="Editar">' +
        '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'+ 
    '</a>' +
'</td>'

$('#tbl_bienSeleccionado').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "columnDefs": [
                {"className": "text-center", "targets": "_all"}
            ],
            "aaData": res.lista,                
            "columns": [
                {"data": "idbien"},
                {"data": "nombre"},
                {"data": "description"},
                {"data": "persona"},
                {"data": "ubicacion"},
                {"data": "estado"},
                {"data": "departamento"}
            ],
          "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, data)
           {
                var id = data[0]; // 1st column in single row array         
                var replacedEditHtml = edithtml.replace("{id}", id); 
                $("td:eq(8)", nRow).html(replacedEditHtml); //replace 8th column
});
```

Comment: The jquery-datatables.js elements do not appear, as the search bar and the drop-down list of items to be displayed; that is to say a simple table appears.
And when I'm adding a function appear this error :TypeError: col is undefined. Thx